# What is this bump on my cats paw

Tags: cats, skin-condition

I only just found this now, it’s on the back of her left hind paw. She doesn’t like her paws being touched regardless, but it doesn’t look like it’s hurting her.
She’s an indoor cat, but I let her out in the back with supervision, she’s 10, and she already has sinus problems. Not sure if that would affect her paws or anything.
It feels just like a regular paw pad
[image]

Comment: Skin tag? Flap of skin from  past injury not yet  resorbed?

Comment: a little hairless area is nothing to worry about,the skin looks healthy and has the same color as your skin.if a cat is limping or show signs of pain that last for more than 30 min you need to contact your vet.

Comment: this is related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28260/stepped-on-my-kittens-paw/28261#28261

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a harmless skin tag. I've seen numerous of them on my dog and I know that other mammals and humans can get them as well. Usually people don't notice them, either because they are hidden in the fur or on humans they have the same color as the skin.

They are just harmless growth of skin that usually don't cause any discomfort. The exception being when they grow in areas that are rubbed regularly (like in the armpits or the creases of the legs) or when they grow from soft tissue like the mouth.

As long as the skin tag stays small, smooth and skin-colored, there's no reason to worry. If it gets red from being rubbed, consider a vet visit to get it removed without much bleeding. If it suddenly grows much bigger or the surface gets bumpy and irregular with red dots or red vein patterns, consult a vet because it may be something else.