# How can I train a cat to stop being underfoot?

Tags: cats, training

My wife and I recently adopted a cat from a local shelter.  She's about a year old, and was understandably pretty shy at first, but has warmed to us over the past few weeks and become very affectionate and friendly.  Perhaps a little bit *too* friendly, in fact.  I find lately that when I walk around the house, she'll often try to come and nuzzle at my ankles *while I'm walking,* which presents a tripping hazard for me and a kick/stomp hazard for her.  No one's gotten hurt yet, but I could easily see it happening.

Is there any way to teach her "stay away from the feet while the humans are using them"?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I understand you completely! One of my rabbits tend to come from behind my view to sniff my ankles while I work in the garden. Make one step back without thinking, and "it" will happen :(

Comment: how to not step on my cat might be the oldest cat related question in human history :) this is sort of related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28260/stepped-on-my-kittens-paw

Comment: Maybe some _has_ a good solution. I unfortunately don’t. We have sort of an arrangement now, after years of bumps and stumbles.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see a way to teach that conditional without stepping on (or at least kicking) the cat a few times. Maybe you could do so gently, pushing the cat away with a foot... Eventually most cats do mostly figure this out, but it generally takes a few mishaps.